# Linux LFS 7.6 problems with audio playback

Tags: linux

I have a laptop with an LFS 7.6 system.

I installed ALSA

```
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/alsa-lib.html
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/alsa-plugins.html
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/alsa-utils.html
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/alsa-tools.html
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/alsa-firmware.html
```

Also I installed

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/multimedia/mpg123.html

When I use mpg123 file.mp3 I get

```
    High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
        version 1.21.0; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
        free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes

Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: file.mp3 ...

[id3.c:465] error: No comment text / valid description?

MPEG 1.0 layer III, 320 kbit/s, 44100 Hz stereo
Title:   Volaverunt Opus 666             Artist: M*go de Oz
Comment:                                 Album:  Gaia II
Year:    2005                            Genre:  Folk Metal
```

But I can't hear any sound.

Searching in Internet I found some checks

modinfo soundcore -> returns to me -> Module soundcore not found

aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: ID 2807 Digital [ID 2807 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ID 76e5 Analog [ID 76e5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of /etc/group

```
audio:x:11:apache,root
```

What I'm doing bad? The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L50-A-1EH

Answer (score 0):

@Guille try to reinstall the sound modules and restart the machine. This might solve your problem. If it still persists do lemme know bro.

Comment: I recompiled kernel enabling as MODULE, you can see in the imgur album

http://imgur.com/LfeGzQ5,j4QXtFA 

when I do alsactl init I get this error:

alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid

Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel ID 2807" "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000" "0x1179" "0xfa49"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method